# How to run with a custom sized windows application in Windows 10

Tags: windows, shell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I want to run the VoxEdit.exe application from https://www.sandbox.game with a custom size.

As far as I know, the start command can only run with /MAX and /MIN arguments.
I don't know in which programming language it is built and it may not allow resizing.
The question remains valid as for any windows application:

***Is it possible to start a windows 10 application with custom sizes?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`STARTUPINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfoa) struct used by `CreateProcess` has the `STARTF_USEPOSITION` and `STARTF_USESIZE` flags and members to set values for them. The system will only respect these values if the application creates its main window as overlapped and with `CW_USEDEFAULT` (Notepad etc.).

I don't see these options in `ProcessStartInfo` so you will have to P/Invoke...

Comment: yes, if this is built like a default windows form, but now I saw the electron can also create windows applications and I suppose the data send to the operating system comes in that manner or less ... maybe this is the reason to not have a resize option.

Comment: It only matters how the application calls CreateWindowEx, nothing else.

Comment: maybe this is the reason why the START command can only run with /MAX and /MIN arguments because is minimal default settings for the window.

Comment: Min/Max are unrelated to the size. ShellExecute and ProcessStartInfo also support specifying Min/Max, not just CreateProcess. Windows enforces this the first time an application calls ShowWindow.